# What is the difference between "Corning Gorilla Glass Victus" and "Corning Gorilla Glass Victus Plus"?

Tags: samsung, screen

What is the difference between "Gorilla Glass Victus" and "Gorilla Glass Victus+"?

Samsung claims their S22 and S22+ and S22U phones have something called

> Corning® Gorilla® Glass Victus®+

The problem is, even on Corning.com I can't find any information on Gorilla Glass Victus+, I can only find information about [Victus](https://www.corning.com/gorillaglass/worldwide/en/glass-types/gorilla-glass-victus.html).

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read, Gorilla Glass Victus+ is a stronger, more scratch-resistant, and more durable version of Gorilla Glass Victus. It was the first time that Corning has collaborated with Samsung, getting the new glass, only for those Samsung devices. 
The plus version of the glass would start to scratch at the level of 7 on Moh's Hardness Scale, while the plus version would be closer to ceramic, with an 8.